# Edited .htaccess on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

In my wp-admin folder i have a file .htaccess with the following code in it.

```
<Files install.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (ip has been changed)
</Files>
```

Is this a hack or something?

Comment: `Do you have any plugins installed?`

Comment: Yes i have a few

Comment: `Which ones? They might tamper with your .htaccess.`

Comment: `Separately, that does look like a suspicious modification. You might want to disable your plugins.`

Comment: I have so many that i cant list them all here. The ip adress is to a large company that is not connected to my website in any way.

Comment: `Oh. You might want to disable the ones that have access to modify your Web site.`

Comment: `Does this happen on a new Web site?`

Comment: Thanks. this is the ip 90.227.151.207 if it helps?

Comment: `Whose Web site is 90.227.151.207? is that yours?`

Comment: No, this is 4 years old code. Im not so good on coding and just found it.

Comment: `Basically, this denies access to your Web site from everyone except those requests coming from 90.227.151.207. Does removing this section make this problem happen again?`

Comment: No, its the ip from the code, to Telia company.

Comment: `Does Telia company author any plugins you have installed? And does your Web site behave strangely?`

Comment: It isnt anything wrong with my website that I know, but this code dosent look right to me.

Comment: `You're right, this code is suspicious. Are you sure this is the real .htaccess file?`

Comment: No plugins or anything to my website.

Comment: `You say this is from four years ago. You probably added it yourself and forgot about it. Or was it a plugin that you uninstalled?`

Comment: (website name)/wp-admin/.htaccess is where the code is

Comment: `Try accessing [Web site name]/wp-admin/[any file name]. Anything strange happen?`

Comment: No i didnt added i know that.

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: `That's the htaccess file in work. It has blocked your request because you do not have an IP address of 90.227.151.207. Try removing the malicious .htaccess code. Does that help?`

Comment: No, I should try to open that in a web browser right?

Comment: `Yes, in a web browser or downloading it with cURL. I can't possibly provide a good tutorial of cURL in this comment, so you can search it up for how to use it. Basically what both of these tools here do is contact the server to try to download the file you specify, and throw an error when an error occurs (such as 404 or 403 or 500). If you cannot access the Web resource with cURL or a trustable Web browser such as Chrome or Firefox, you can try different browsers. If that still doesn't work, you can conclude that the resource is unavailable since a lot of trusted browsers cannot download it.`

Comment: Well looks like i can access files in wp-admin now. strange...

Comment: `Looks like a suspicious plugin. Try creating a new Web site and see if the htaccess modifications are applied onto the new Web site.`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know why a large company would put that code there?

Comment: It would be a huge job to create a new website with all plugins. My website is working fine what i know of.

Comment: But i can try to do that, I only need to install the same plugins not the same theme?

Comment: `I'm a bit late, but here: A large company might want to reduce traffic to your site and increase traffic to their own Web site. And yes, when creating a new Web site, you don't have to install the same themes to test the plugins, only the same plugins.`

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Telia is the largest telecom company we have here in Sweden. My website has 100 visitors/day and Im pretty sure that is not the trafic they want. Do you know exactly what they can do with that code?

Comment: `Again, they can block access to everyone except 90.227.151.207. This might get them to access your resources while everyone else is blocked out.`

Comment: Okey thanks, Im pretty bad at understanding coding. Is it legal to do someting like that?

Comment: `I'm not a lawyer, but I believe that it infringes on the site's owner in the US. (Don't believe me completely. Ask on Law.StackExchange.com if you need to really know this.)`

Comment: `Probably just another attempt to prank a web site owner. Try removing the htaccess code.`